# force a pointer to reset on postgres result array

Tags: php

I am attempting to make a calendar for my salesman of what sort of clients they have lined up for the week.

There is a table that I have that stores each lined up client as an entry.

I have an SQL statement that scoops all this up and I am trying to get a layout that looks like:

```
Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday
```

And then I want to dump all the entries as divs under each of this columns in the table.

The sql data is not grouped by day, so it will return something like:

```
array("Monday","Joe blow"); // index 0
array("Monday","Sally Smith"); // index 1
```

and so on.

I have this placed right after the result is retrieve from the statement:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result,null,PGSQL_ASSOC) {

}
```

And this iterates through each row.

However what happens when I need to dump more than one row under a single column?

I was thinking some code along the line of:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result,null,PGSQL_ASSOC)) {

    while ($row['day']=="Monday") {
       echo '<div>'.$row['client_name'].'</div>';
    }

    while ($row['day']=="Tuesday") {
       echo '<div>'.$row['client_name'].'</div>';
    }

}
```

however that didn't go anywhere as it seems to return `true` everytime it hits "Thursday" because the pointer hasn't reset on the original while loop to fetch the next record.

I am trying to figure out a clean way to set the pointer to the next record and start again at the original `while` loop.

Anybody got an idea on this??

Thanks a million!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-seek.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

The function to use is `pg_result_seek()` as covered in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-seek.php)

Thank you rjdown!